# Data path for driver: secret of 'node_tree.'

Tags: drivers, path, data-blocks

1) I prepared two objects for driving.
[image]

2) I copied the data path of the color property of diffuse shader in Suzanne's material node to drive the box.
`nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value` : failure
[image]

3) This time, I found the Data Api in the outliner, do copy data path, and created an index at the end of the path.
`nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[0]` : failure
[image]

4) This time I copied the property values that are displayed in the info window.
`bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[0]` : failure
[image]

5) I found a solution to use the `node_tree.` prefix via googling.
`node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[0]` : Eventually succeed
`node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[1]` : succeed
`node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[2]` : succeed
`node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value[3]` : succeed
`node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value.r` : succeed
`node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value.g` : succeed
`node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value.b` : succeed
`node_tree.nodes["Diffuse BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value.a` : succeed
But I can't figure out what `node_tree.` Is and where it comes from.
[image]

6) I want to figure out exactly the rules for dealing with data paths.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a driver with the property set to material, you're implicitly using a reference to an object of type [`bpy.types.Material`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html).

Your first attempts in step 2) and 3) didn't work because `bpy.types.Material` has no attribute called `node`. The idea in step 4) has the same problem as the previous attempts, because the driver tries to access these attributes in the material object of type `bpy.types.Material` and since there is no `bpy.types.Material.bpy` this fails as well.

The correct way to access the nodes is indeed through [`node_tree`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html#bpy.types.Material.node_tree) since that is an attribute in the object of type `bpy.types.Material`. It gives you access to all [`nodes`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeTree.html#bpy.types.NodeTree.nodes) in the referenced material.

Attempt 6) fails again because there is no `shader_nodetree` in [`bpy.types.Material.node_tree`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeTree.html).

For questions like these you can always consult [Blender's Python API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html).

Comment: Oh, I think I know a bit.

I'll ask you a little bit more.

After that, I copied the transform data path into a driver single property. `location [0]`

It worked fine but I was puzzled. The material attribute required a prefix of `node_tree`, but the transform attribute works without any prefix.

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @J.SungHoon Just to be sure I'm understanding you right. You have a variable that is a *Single Property*, the *Prop* is set to an object and *Path* is set to `location[0]`? That works because you're using an object as property (`bpy.types.Object`) which has a location attribute. See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.location

Comment: It gave me a lot of hints. I haven't learned Python specifically yet so I can't easily navigate the documentation you link to, but after learning Python I came back to see your answer again. Thank you.